# Java 8 LocalDate to JavaScript Date

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, localdate

I would like to convert this Java `LocalDate` to a JavaScript `Date`:

```
{
    "date": {
        "year": 2016,
        "month": "NOVEMBER",
        "dayOfMonth": 15,
        "monthValue": 11,
        "dayOfWeek": "TUESDAY",
        "era": "CE",
        "dayOfYear": 320,
        "leapYear": true,
        "chronology": {
            "id": "ISO",
            "calendarType": "iso8601"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your date string does not specify a time zone. You are also missing time information, while JavaScript dates store the time of day by design.

Your string is nearly valid JSON, so you can parse it via `JSON.parse()`. It is only missing one closing `}` bracket.

Considering the remarks above, you could use the following approach:

```js
var input = JSON.parse('{"date":{"year":2016,"month":"NOVEMBER","dayOfMonth":15,"monthValue":11,"dayOfWeek":"TUESDAY","era":"CE","dayOfYear":320,"leapYear":true,"chronology":{"id":"ISO","calendarType":"iso8601"}}}');
            
var day = input.date.dayOfMonth;
var month = input.date.monthValue - 1; // Month is 0-indexed
var year = input.date.year;

var date = new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day));

console.log(date); // "2016-11-15T00:00:00.000Z"
```

Comment: The timezone isn't "missing" - it is excluded by design. This is a LocalDate.

Answer (score 5):

When you send temporal types from Java to other systems you should be unambiguous about things like time of day and timezone. If the instance really is a *Local* Date you don't want to convert it to an instant on the universal timeline by selecting some arbitrary timezone. UTC is arbitrary. So is the *default* timezone.

14 March 2016 should mean the same thing to systems on opposite sides of the globe. ISO8601 exists for this purpose.

I recommend that when sending your Java LocalDate to your JS client by encoding it in JSON as a string in ISO8601 format using `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE.format(localDate)` and parse from JSON using `LocalDate.parse(text, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)`.

JavaScript's `Date` is more like the old Java `Date` class and is similarly misnamed. However JavaScript's `Date` will happily parse ISO8601 formatted strings either by construction or via the `Date.parse()` function and will produce ISO8601 strings via `Date.toISOString()`. Just note that JavaScript will interpret a missing timezone (signifying Local values in Java) as UTC. You can be unambiguous by always using the Zulu timezone when you mean UTC and assuming JS clients always send you zoned values.

Or just use JS-Joda.